# Civil Wars Quest - Legate Rikke Dialogs Bug

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I recently having some issues with Legate Rikke's dialogs. I seems can't find the solutions. I can't get the option to report for the next war and yes, **I have tried to kill her before**. It yet still failed. Anyone know what is the solution? I'm using **PC version** by the way.

Comment: What is the exact quest and instruction you are trying to fulfill?  The war quest line doesn't always have you reporting to her directly.  It can send you to an area to regroup with soldiers to attack a fort.

Comment: The quest maker tell me to report to Legate Rikke. I believe that she is located Falkreath Imperial Camp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once I had the same issue. I fixed it by going back to the general and clearing the white text (particularly spamming "How goes the war?"), but it can also be fixed by making sure you're on the opposite side of the table, using the cooking split at the center of the camp, and repeatedly pulling up a different conversation until it pops up.